# LINQ to SQL GroupBy, Take and OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, group-by

I have a table with records

```
|   ID      |   FKID    |   Date        |   Username        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   A       |   a1      |   01/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   B       |   a1      |   02/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   C       |   b1      |   03/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   D       |   b1      |   04/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   E       |   c2      |   05/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   F       |   c2      |   06/01/01    |       Joe         |
```

I want to select 3 records with distinct `FKID` ordered with the latest date first belonging to `Joe`.

```
|   F       |   c2      |   06/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   D       |   b1      |   04/01/01    |       Joe         |
|   B       |   a1      |   02/01/01    |       Joe         |
```

I can achieve this for one record:

```
Table.Where(a => a.Username.Equals("Joe"))
     .GroupBy(a => a.FKID)
     .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
     .ToList<Record>();
```

but cannot get `Take()` and `OrderByDecending()` to work correctly.

Comment: `.Select(g => g.OrderBy(d=>d.Date).LastOrDefault())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `OrderByDescending` :-

```
Table.Where(a => a.Username.Equals("Joe"))
     .GroupBy(a => a.FKID)
     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())
     .Take(3)
     .ToList<Record>();
```